# I am importing MongoClient from my other service to make it reusable and not installing mongodb packages unnecessarily but I am facing an issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb

Error: 'MongoClient' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MongoClient'?

Exporting from service 1 named **dbconnection**:

```
import * as mongodb from "mongodb";
export const ObjectId =  mongodb.ObjectId;
export const ReadPreference =  mongodb.ReadPreference;
export const MongoClient =  mongodb.MongoClient;
export { mongodb };
```

Using the same in my service 2

```
 import { MongoClient, getReturnDbClient } from '@MyApp/dbconnection';
export class ReturnsDbProvider {


constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}
  async getReturnsDbConnection(): Promise<Connection> {
    try {
    const env = this.configService.get<string>('database.env');
    const dbName = `${env}-lma-returns`;
      const client: MongoClient = await getReturnDbClient();
      if (!client) {
        logger.error(`Failed to connect with Return Database`);
        throw new BadRequestException('Internal Server Error.');
      }
      const connection = mongoose
        .createConnection()
        .setClient(client)
        .useDb(dbName);
      if (!connection) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Internal Server Error.");
      }
      logger.debug(`Connected To Return Database!`);
      return connection;
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(`Failed to connect with Return Database, Error: ${error}`);
    }
  }

}
```

Getting this error
[image]